# Authorization plugins for RoR with Rails 3 support

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Please name RoR authorization plugins with Rails 3 support, which you think is the best.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Do you need an Authorization or Authentication plugin? It seems that everyone is giving you Authentication plugin.

**Authentication**

To verify user with its credentials so she can get in to the system

[devise](http://github.com/plataformatec/devise) is one of Authentication plugin that works well (out of the box) with Rails 3:

**Authorization**

To verify whether the logged in user is allowed to access certain feature in the system

Here are the list of Authorization plugin in Rails (that works well with Rails 3).

- [CanCan](http://github.com/ryanb/cancan)
- [Declarative Authorization](http://github.com/stffn/declarative_authorization)

CanCan is much simpler and straight forward. Decl_auth is much cleaner and can get pretty difficult to work with at some stage. Hope that helps.

Comment: This is the best answer here, however @sonia has said pretty much the same thing.

Answer (score 11):

I would highly recommend [Devise](http://github.com/plataformatec/devise) - it works perfectly with Rails 3, and in my experience the developers are very helpful in answering questions in the Devise [Google Group](http://groups.google.com/group/plataformatec-devise). There are also two railscasts on Devise - http://railscasts.com/episodes/209-introducing-devise and http://railscasts.com/episodes/210-customizing-devise. [CanCan](http://github.com/ryanb/cancan) is an authorization solution that can be used in tandem with Devise - check out the [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan), this plugin again works great with Rails 3. Hope that helps!

Comment: It's also worth noting that Devise is actually more than a simple plugin - it is a rails engine. This means that Devise is essentially a miniature rails application (complete with its own routes and views) that integrates with and enhances your own, while allowing you to override any part of the engine you want (such as the views or routes).

Comment: Authlogic is still the biggest, but to start a new site from scratch, devise is much easier. Authlogic is just the backend, and can integrate with any existing site, and it is around longer. Devise is the new kid on the block, it uses warden, is a rails engine. Devise integrates perfectly with Rails3. Authlogic works in rails3 but that is less obvious (it took me a while).

Comment: Devise is used for **authentication** not **authorization**, these are two different things.

Answer (score 2):

Authlogic (http://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic) is a great rails authorization solution, and it works in rails3 as well

And if you want to check if a plugin is compatible with rails 3 go here

http://www.railsplugins.org/

hope this helps

cheers

sameera

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the options here - http://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_authorization.html

As for Rails 3 compatibility, the READMEs of these gems/plugins would be the best place to check. If they don't explicitly say so, they are not !!

Answer (score 1):

For authorization, I have had good experiences with [acl9](https://github.com/be9/acl9)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend devise.