# User membership pattern rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, rubygems

In the .Net world we have the Membership provider, with this we can fully automate user registration and management. Does such a gem exist for the Ruby on Rails community.

I am looking for something that would allow a user to register, retrieve lost password, modify password and login.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the answers given to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3590041/authorization-plugins-for-ror-with-rails-3-support/3590150#3590150) recently - again, I would highly recommend [Devise](http://github.com/plataformatec/devise) and the two railscasts on it, http://railscasts.com/episodes/209-introducing-devise and http://railscasts.com/episodes/210-customizing-devise. Devise handles all the things you described above - from the GitHub page:

- "Confirmable: sends emails with confirmation instructions and verifies whether an account is already confirmed during sign in.
- Recoverable: resets the user password and sends reset instructions.
- Registerable: handles signing up users through a registration process, also allowing them to edit and destroy their account."

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that it has all of the features you want, but I really like restful-authentication.

http://agilewebdevelopment.com/plugins/restful_authentication

**Features per website:**

Login / logout

Secure password handling

Account activation by validating email

Account approval / disabling by admin

Rudimentary hooks for authorization and access control.

It also makes an appearance in a screen cast over at http://www.buildingwebapps.com/learningrails
Episode 11 about adding User Authentication. Watch the others if you are 100% new to rails, but if you just want to see them use the gem, skip to that one.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Devise - http://github.com/plataformatec/devise

It's a popular Rails engine for user authentication and should do what you need (and more).

Answer (score 0):

Check [railscasts](http://railscasts.com/) for a number of new [options](http://railscasts.com/?tag_id=25), including OmniAuth, Sorcery (my choice this week), and authentication from scratch, which may be less painful than the options listed before.