# DRY me: Rails code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, dry

How can I dry this ?

```
def correct_user
  @company = RealEstateCompany.find(params[:id])     
  if(current_user != @company.user)
    redirect_to(root_path)
  end
end  

def correct_user
 @company = ConstructionCompany.find(params[:id])     
 if(current_user != @company.user)
   redirect_to(root_path)
 end
end
```

The answer is below and it's as followed in a module:

```
def correct_user_for_controller?(controller_name)
  @company = controller_name.classify.constantize.find(params[:id])     
  redirect_to(root_path) unless (current_user == @company.user)
end
```

Then inside any controller include the model and use

```
correct_user_for_controller?("ConstructionCompany") 

correct_user_for_controller?("RealEstateCompany")
```

Comment: Is there a reason RealEstateCompany and ConstructionCompany are separate models? This would be DRYer if you just had one Company model.

Comment: Yes RealEstateCompany is different from ConstructionCompany in several ways, for instance ConstructionCompany has_many: projects while RealEstateCompany does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have want this facility inside `ConstructionCompaniesController` and `RealEstateCompaniesController`:

```
def correct_user
  @company = controller_name.classify.constantize.find(params[:id])     
  redirect_to(root_path) unless (current_user == @company.user)
end
```

Comment: Yeah, this is although not very well explained but gave enough to come up with the answer !

Answer (score 3):

```
module OwnershipPermission
    def accessible_for_user?(user)
        self.user == user
    end
end
```

Simply include this module in both models and perform the model level check.
   You could also create a module for the controller, but I highly advise against that (hurts maintainability).

Comment: The problem is not were to put the current_user != @company.user, the problem is finding the current user, I have to find it through  @company = ConstructionCompany.find(params[:id])

Comment: What's wrong with `@company = ConstructionCompany.find(params[:id])`?

Comment: Yep I think I just can't dry this code, there 4 models were I have the same method correct_user, where I find the instance requested using the controller and then check the owner

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are trying to do an authorization check (</clippy>).

Have you checked out any of the existing comprehensive authorization solutions? It might make sense to leverage the effort of others in solving this common problem.

This [thread on authorization for rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3590041/authorization-plugins-for-ror-with-rails-3-support) gives some examples. In particular, with [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) you could include something like this in the method you are trying to protect:

```
authorize! :read, @company
```

Which says "does the current user have permission to see the details of @company".