# only allow specific users to access model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller, authentication

so first my model structure:

> company has many users, user belongs to company
>
> model1 belongs to company, company has many model1
>
> model2 belongs to company, company has many model2

for the index action of model1 i simply do something like

```
@model1 = current_user.company.model1s # i use devise for auth
```

in my controller i put first

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!
```

the problem is, the show action (of course) shows every logged in user every record of model one.

what is the best option to restrict model1 and model2 records only to users that belong to the company the model1 and model2 are belonging to?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the general case, use a plugin or gem like (in no particular order) [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan), [Clearance](https://github.com/thoughtbot/clearance) or one of the others [here](https://github.com/search?langOverride=Ruby&q=authorization&type=Repositories).  For what it's worth, I've used [acl9](https://github.com/be9/acl9) successfully in the past.

Most of these solutions implement authorization control at the controller/view level, and control access to specific instances of models (AKA rows in the database) that way.

Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3590041/authorization-plugins-for-ror-with-rails-3-support), which covers the topic from the perspective of which is best.

Finally, if you want to roll your own, the simplest solution is to join from `model1` and `model2` to `company` and `user` in your queries.  From your description, `model1` and `model2` have a `company_id` column, and `company` has a `user_id` column.  Depending on how you have the associations in your models set up, you could do something like:

```
Model1.joins(:company => :user).where(:users => {:id => 1})
```

or (assuming an appropriate authentication framework):

```
Model1.joins(:company => :user).where(:users => {:id => current_user.id})
```

Comment: thank you for this post. going with cancan now which works great so far.